# Embedding an offline Dashcode application in a UIWebView in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, dashcode

In order words, can anyone tell me the basics of how to create a "hybrid" iPhone application? I want to load the web content (the Dashcode app itself) from the native application's application bundle.

I've gotten this to partially work, but some content won't display and it otherwise seems like Dashcode is assuming a certain Safari environment or something that I don't seem to have in my UIWebView.

Can anyone provide a link to some sample code that embeds a Dashcode project into a cocoa touch Xcode project?

(I did search around Google for a bit trying to find something and I failed to come up with anything worthwhile, except for some books that I might eventually buy if the approach seems worthwhile.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I answered my own question here. It looks like http://quickconnect.sourceforge.net/browser/index.html will show me want I want to know even if I don't actually use the framework.